# Errors thrown within a flow are returned to the rpc client as an InternalNodeException, how do we improve error reporting?

Tags: exception, reporting, corda

We are trying to implement better error reporting coming out of our Corda flows, but we're seeing that any errors thrown within a flow are returned to the RPC-client as an InternalNodeException.

Is there a recommended way to return more details to the client when we need it?

Answer (score 0):

To improve the information provided back to the RPC-Client make the exception type implement `ClientRelevantError`.

This is a feature that we plan to delete: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-2740